# Can we induce e.m.f. with magnetic field without any change in flux

Tags: induction

An e.m.f. is developed when there is a change in flux. Can we induce e.m.f. without any change in flux? Is it against Faraday's law?

Comment: No, that is actually what is described by the law. However you can get a change in flux by changing the relative position of conductors(or magnetic circuit elements), and not only the inducing currents.
It is a bit like asking does the law of "x" describe "x".

Comment: I wanted to ask that if current is induced by the magnetic field without change in magnetic flux, will it be the violation of Faraday's law?

Comment: Yes it will be a violation. Faradays law says $\frac{d\Phi}{{d}t}=-U$. The induction of voltage triggers a current.
You can write the formula in a less mathematical way:
$\frac{\Phi(t_2)-\Phi(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}=-U$. This can be used when $t_2-t_1$ is small.

Comment: I think I have an idea in which current will flow due to the motional e.m.f. but no change in flux. It will produce a pure D.C.(without any fluctuations) when the rod is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faraday's law in its integral form can be stated that the induced EMF is proportional to the *rate of change of magnetic flux linking a circuit*.

There are a number of ways to arrange this, but of course all of them involve changing the magnetic flux through a circuit.

Faraday's law in this form only applies to a *circuit* made up of *thin* wire. Finite-sized conductors can have induced EMFs through a direct application of the Lorentz force law. The motion of charge in a magnetic field results in a force perpendicular to the velocity and magnetic field. In an isolated conductor this results in a movement/separation of charge and an induced voltage across the conductor even though there is no change in magnetic flux linking the conductor.

Whilst this appears not to obey Faraday's law, it does obey the differential form of Faraday's law, namely that $\nabla \times {\bf E} = -\partial {\bf B}/\partial t$. An example of this "motional" EMF is the [homopolar generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_generator), which defies application of Faraday's law.

Other examples of these paradoxes, where the EMF can be better described in terms of a Lorentz force are described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox#Paradoxes_in_which_Faraday.27s_law_of_induction_predicts_zero_EMF_but_there_is_a_non-zero_EMF).